# Magento custom product attribute visibility

Tags: php, magento, attributes, visibility, entity-attribute-value

I've been loading up my Magento webshop with a ton of products with a LOT of custom attributes, however, their 'Visible' value in the back end is set to 'No'.

Apart from this being a mistake on my part (and those who helped me fill this product database), I can't seem to find a way to set the attribute visibility to Yes.

I've tried looking up the `attribute_id` (102) in `eav_attribute` for `attribute_code` 'visibility', and wanted to set this to another value in `catalog_product_entity_int`, but then it dawned on me that "I must have at least 1 attribute set to visible, so I must have at least one record where this value is not 4". After writing a small query that excluded 4, I found that I was left with no records at all.

What am I doing wrong? Am I looking at the wrong table here?

Is there another way to set all the 'visible' attributes for the attributes themselves to 'Yes'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the table you're looking for is `catalog_eav_attribute`, which has a column `is_visible` and another `is_visible_on_front`: put 1 (one) for the attributes you want to make visible.

Comment: who said Magento was difficult? ;)